# Regex - extract string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have this string
`DOCPROPERTY "EndDate"  \\* MERGEFORMAT`

and am trying to extract the field name: "EndDate"
Using the code:

```
 Dim p As String = "(.*)DOCPROPERTY(?<field>(.*))MERGEFORMAT(.*)"
 For Each a As RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(t, p, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            MsgBox(a.Groups("field").Value)
 Next
```

but get this result `"EndDate" \\*`

I tried a couple ways to get rid of `\\*`

I need as result just `EndDate`

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

`DOCPROPERTY "(?<field>\w+)"`

Macthing only the words inside `"` and preceded by the word `DOCPROPERTY`

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/J7TLEZ/2) (*updated*)

**Update:**

Your new string exemple is also working with this regex, be sure to mark the `Multline` option on regex:

```
Regex.Matches(t, p, RegexOptions.Multline)
```

Comment: Thanks, Matheus, but it didn't work. try with this string:
"{\li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid5260874 {\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5260874  DOCPROPERTY  "EndDate" \\* MERGEFORMAT }
}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5260874 EndDate}}}\sectd \ltrsect\linex0\endnhere\sectdefaultcl\sftnbj {\rtlch\fcs1 par \cell }\pard \ltrpar\ql ..."

Comment: @Jeff.K Feel free to mark as answer if it helped you :)